# Python's regex star quantifier not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to select only groups of words within quotation marks.

**Example.**

Input:

```
this is 'a sentence' with less 'than twenty words'
```

Output:

```
['a sentence', 'than twenty words']
```

The regex I'm using is:

```
'\'[\w]+[ ]+[[\w]+[ ]+]*[\w]+\''
```

But it's just returning the 'than twenty words'. In fact, it only returns the strings with two spaces.

Comment: What function are you using to match your input against the regular expression?

Comment: re.findall(), @chepner

Comment: You should learn more about **character classes** and **groups**.

Comment: You should not use character classes inside character classes in Python re, you ruin the pattern that way. Try using `re.findall(r"'\w+(?:\s+\w+)*'", s)`.

Comment: To match 2 or more words, use `re.findall(r"'\w+(?:\s+\w+)+'", s)`, see https://regex101.com/r/32kjbw/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
re.findall(r"\'(\s*\w+\s+\w[\s\w]*)\'", input_string)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TgdE1y/5)

Comment: @Claudia, the previous solution was a bit buggy, use updated one.

Answer (score 1):

This will deliver the strings between quotation marks, including words and spaces.

```py
import re
st = "this is 'a sentence' with less 'than twenty words'"
re.findall(r"\'([\w|\s]+)\'", st)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
sentence = "this is 'a sentence' with less 'than twenty words' and a 'lonely' word"
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=')\w+(?:\s+\w+)+(?=')")
regex.findall(sentence)
# ['a sentence', 'than twenty words']
```

We want to capture strings starting and ending with quotes, without capturing them, so we use a positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=')` before, and a lookahead assertion `(?=')` afterwards.

Inside the quotes, we want to have at least one word, followed by at least one group of space and word. We don't want it to be a capturing group, otherwise `findall` would return only this group, so we make it non-catching by using `(?:....)`.

Comment: I accepted Ahsanul's answer for being published before, but your's is correct also. Voted up. Ty.

Comment: @Claudia: Note that your question requested the quotes to be left out of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can use:

```
import re
string = "this is 'a sentence' with less 'than twenty words'"
result = re.findall("'(.*?)'", string)
print result
# ['a sentence', 'than twenty words']
```

---

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/iyCxTm)
[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d2shRD/1)